# How to order data by ONLY Hour:Minute format in MongoDB/Mongoid? (Without date!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I'm using MongoDB and Mongoid in my project. I have some difficulties with ordering "Time" field data.

As you know, eventhough you set a field type as `Time` inside your Mongoid Document, time data is stored as this format (note that I use +2 hours offset to get my own timezone's time instead of UTC):

`Mon, 31 Dec 2012 08:30:00 EET +02:00`

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but this is what happens to me.

I want to use that `Time` data inside one of my views. I need to sort some related stuff by ONLY `Hour:Minute` format. I don't want Rails to take care of the DATE part of the field data. Because whenever a new `Time` record inserted to DB, it takes the day info as CURRENT DAY.

### Issue is:

Because of it saves CURRENT DAY for each of new `Time` records, when I try to `order_by("hour DESC")` NEW records always retrieved first eventhough HOUR part of the data is bigger!

### For example:

```
First data:
=> Tue, 27 Nov 2012 19:50:00 EET +02:00
Second data:
=> Mon, 24 Dec 2012 18:45:00 EET +02:00
```

As you know, normally, 19:50 is bigger than 18:45. But in this scenario, because of Rails takes `day` info into calculation, 18:45 looks like bigger than 19:50!

So what is the work around for this issue?

Thanks in advence.

Comment: may this will hep you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048620/mongoid-query-by-date-ranges

Comment: I can't see any similarities between my question and your recommendation? Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry !! I will look deep upon your question

Comment: Thanks any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to this at Mongoid's issues list:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1169

That's really weired...

If I understood well, `Time` field type is totally useless! What is the difference between `DateTime` and `Time` then??

You even can not compare hours and minutes ONLY inside a `Time` field.

And hold your breath for the work around...

### Solution is:

Not to use `Time` field type! Just use `String` and compare hours and dates via that procedure.

```
Person.where(:time.gt => "13:00")
```

If some could explain this weired situation, I would be happy.

Comment: also add "0" to beggining of string if hours less than "10".

Answer (score 1):

Best way to store time of day is as seconds_since_midnight in an Integer field. Then you can just sort normally.

```
field :time, type: Integer
validates :time, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 86399 }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-seconds_since_midnight
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-seconds_since_midnight