# Compare two params in MongoID on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying make a query like this in Rails using MongoID:

> "Find Tasks Where Date is less than Done_date and Done_date is between the beginning of this week and the end of this week"

I found an way to compare two elements inside the Mongo id using:

```
Tasks.collection.find({"$where" => 'this.date >= this.done_date'})
```

But I really don't know how can I add the date range inside this.

Comment: Kindly check with _http://stackoverflow.com/a/8052619/3098330_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Tasks.where('$where' => 'this.date >= this.done_date')
```

Comment: I'm happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.